# Generics on React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having a bit of trouble trying to make a little component work with typescript generics:

```js
export interface ButtonProps {
  as?: "button" | "a";
}

export type ButtonType<E = HTMLButtonElement> = React.FC<ButtonProps & React.HTMLAttributes<E>>;

export const Button: ButtonType = ({ ... }) => ...;
```

Depending on what is passed in `as`, the element renders as a different HTML Element. As buttons and anchors are quite different, I would like it to be able to make it understand at what point which attributes are allowed and which aren't.

So I thought this is a good place for a generic. What does need to change is what is inside `React.HTMLAttributes`. If I am somehow able to use the component with `<Button<HTMLAnchorElement>>...</Button>` then that is fine with me. Though maybe there is a different method to do this that is more elegant.

But I cannot find a way to make the component accept a generic. `Button: ButtonType<E>` does not work either.

Comment: Please check if this is what you are trying to achieve - https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-boyd-y16t4j?file=/src/App.tsx